# Decoding XML with base64_decode works fine in PHPUnit but returns UTF-16 encoded data in browser

Tags: php, drupal, encoding, base64

I'm having some strange issues with decoding an XML snippet, contained with a cookie, with PHP's [base64_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) function:

1. In our PHPUnit tests, we can decode the XML and echo it out to the console and it prints XML as you would expect (all unit tests pass as well).
2. As soon as we try running the same code in the browser, the decoded XML appears to contain loads of UTF-16 characters interspersed with fragments of the expected XML tags. For example:

   <CreateSession\u000f\u0013Y...

As you might then expect, we end up with an **Exception: String could not be parsed as XML...** error when passing this string to the [SimpleXMLElement constructor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php).

Some further info:

- The XML itself comes from an external login system and we don't have any control over it's format; it doesn't come with any <?xml...?> declaration and the root node is this <CreateSession>...</CreateSession> tag.
- I've checked the character encoding of the page being served and have verified that it is UTF-8.
- The site being developed is using Drupal
- We tried passing the XML / UTF-16 string through Drupal's [drupal_convert_to_utf8](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_convert_to_utf8/6) function, but this just returns the Chinese (I think) symbols e.g. 敲

Has anyone come across anything like this before or have any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Isn't that a CR and a Tab? could you post some of the source before it is decoded?

Comment: Not sure - \u000f is listed as SHIFT IN and the console output from the unit tests contains no CR or tabs if that's any help. And by "source before it is decoded" do you mean the PHP code or the base64 encoded XML?

Comment: The base 64 encoded XML. if you can?

Comment: As it comes from an external login system I don't think I can - sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! It turns out that, when run in the browser, the cookie values were automatically [URL decoded](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) by PHP, meaning that any '+' in the base64 encoded text were being replaced by spaces. Adding this line of code before calling `base64_decode` fixed things:

```
$tmp = str_replace(' ', '+', $value);
```